Loading changepage causes tikzpagenodes to incorrectly identify marginpar nodes

Once changepage is loaded, tikzpagenodes does not correctly identify the nodes of marginpar, but geometry package still identifies it correctly
My MWE
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\geometry{twoside=false,showframe=true}
\geometry{left=35mm,right=10mm,includemp=true}
\geometry{marginparsep=5mm,marginparwidth=20mm}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
% BEGIN_FOLD

% Main text
\NewDocumentCommand{\pageframeMainText}{O{0.75} O{gray}   O{0pt}}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=#1, color=#2]
        \draw[line width=#3]
        (current page text area.north west)
        rectangle
        (current page text area.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% Marginpar
\NewDocumentCommand{\pageframeMarginPar}{O{0.75} O{gray} O{0pt}}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=#1, color=#2]
        \draw[line width=#3]
        (current page marginpar area.north west)
        rectangle
        (current page marginpar area.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox
\marginnote{jumps over the lazy dog}

\begin{adjustwidth}{0mm}{-\dimexpr \marginparsep + \marginparwidth \relax}

\smash{\rlap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.1pt}}}

\end{adjustwidth}

\pageframeMainText
\pageframeMarginPar

\end{document}


If you load changepage before tikzpagenodes, the confusion goes away.
